# LWCs - Navigation Menu Base?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, navigation

I am in the process of building a custom navigation menu as a Lightning Web Component for my community.

I know that in Aura Components one could use `forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase`, which provides data about the community's navigation menu items.

**How could one gather navigation menu data for the community the when writing an LWC?**

The documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase/documentation does not seem to indicate there is a direct equivalent for LWCs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@wire](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about) function to call an Apex method that returns list of menu items using this SOQL query `SELECT Label, NavigationLinkSetId, Target FROM NavigationMenuItem`.